# Usar el ORM para contar el numero de veces que aparece un producto después de un M2M

Tags: python, django, orm

Estoy trabajando en un sistema en el cual se crean unos ciclos de alimentación, cada ciclo contendrá diferentes menús, el menú hace referencia a los alimentos que se consumen en el día. En general cada ciclo contiene 5 menús.

Esto se puede entender que menú corresponde a la alimentación del día y ciclo a la alimentación de los días hábiles de una semana.

Ahora, cada menú esta compuesto por 3 platos, (desayuno, refrigerio y almuerzo) cada plato contiene los alimentos (productos) que una persona va a consumir.

A continuación los modelos principales y el diagrama entidad relación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Modelo ciclo

```
class Ciclo(FormatoCampos, Auditable):
    """
    Un ciclo contiene los menús
    """
    numero = models.SmallIntegerField(
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        verbose_name=_('número')
    )
    menus = models.ManyToManyField(
        Menu,
        verbose_name=_('menús'),
        related_name='ciclo_menu'
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('ciclo')
        verbose_name_plural = _('ciclos')

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Ciclo %s' % self.numero
```

Modelo menú

```
class Menu(FormatoCampos, Auditable):
    """
    Un menú se define por números (menu1, menu2, menu3, etc)
    """
    numero = models.SmallIntegerField(
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        verbose_name=_('número')
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('menú')
        verbose_name_plural = _('menús')

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Menú %s' % self.numero
```

Modelo plato

```
class Plato(FormatoCampos, Auditable):
    """
    Un plato define los productos que se dan en cada momento de alimentación de un menú
    """
    menu = models.ForeignKey(
        Menu,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        verbose_name=_('menú'),
        related_name='plato_menu',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    momento_alimentacion = models.ForeignKey(
        MomentoAlimentacion,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        verbose_name=_('momento de alimentación'),
        related_name='plato_momento_alimentacion',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    productos = models.ManyToManyField(
        Producto,
        verbose_name=_('productos'),
        related_name='palto_productos'
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('plato')
        verbose_name_plural = _('platos')

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.momento_alimentacion.__str__(), self.menu.__str__())
```

Como se puede evidenciar un `ciclo` contiene un campo `menus` que es de tipo `ManyToMany` y un `plato` esta relacionado a un `menu`.

Para calcular el numero de productos consumidos en la semana estoy realizando el siguiente proceso
1 Obtener los menús del ciclo `menus = Ciclo.objects.get(id=id_cliclo).menus.all()`
2 Recorrer los menús resultantes y obtener los platos de cada menú

```
platos = None
for menu in menus:
    if platos:
        platos = menu.plato_menu.all() | platos
    else:
        platos = menu.plato_menu.all()
```

3 recorrer los platos e ir contando cada producto.

Con esto lo que consigo es contar, cuantas veces se consume pan, cuantas veces se consume huevo, cuantas veces se consume x producto.

La pregunta es:
Como puedo contar el numero de productos consumidos en un ciclo de forma mas optima usando el ORM?